# Is it possible to load platform specific .net libraries in net core?

Tags: c#, reflection, .net-core, cross-platform

My goal is to create a plugin type structure where my net core 2.0 library attempts to load an unknown (until runtime) type by reflecting through libraries in a folder.

Some of these types may require platform specific implementations.
I've attempted this by dynamically loading a .net framework 4.6.1 library (which in turn depends on `System.Windows.Forms`) but when the code attempts to invoke a method on the successfully constructed type I receive the following exception:

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058)

Reading [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/how-to-load-assemblies-into-the-reflection-only-context) it suggests that the dependant `System.Windows.Forms.dll` must be being loaded into the wrong context?

First question, is there something simple I need to change to get this to work?
Secondly, is this sort of thing even possible? (mixing core with platform specific libraries)
Is there a better way to be doing this that I'm unaware of? Google is turning up decidedly limited documentation.

Comment: Xamarin sort of does this (or used to), it uses one portable class library project and gives you project specific implementations for Windows, Android and Mac. See how the Solution/Projects is setup: http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/image1.png I recall it does a lot of this with Partial Classes and compile flags - good luck trying to do it *dynamically at run time*.

Comment: The project types (.NET Core and .NET Framework) are incompatible, https://blog.lextudio.com/which-class-library-project-to-go-in-visual-studio-2015-2017-a48710cf3dff So your wishes won't come true.

Answer (score 3):

No, loading .Net Framework assemblies from .Net Core won't work.

> Windows Forms and WPF in particular will forever remain in the .Net Framework as Windows Universal applications have become the new UI creed. Anything that relies on platform-specific features will also be excluded. 
>   - [Ben Morris](http://www.ben-morris.com/sharing-libraries-between-net-core-and-net-framework-applications/)

.Net Core and .Net Framework assembly are different and can't interact with each other.

Thus, your plugin system can only load .Net Core or .Net Standard assemblies. If you really need .Net Framework support (or other languages), you could interact with the plugins via `Process.Start()` and passing arguments via stdin/runtime arguments.

Comment: This has been my working theory up until now. I have coincidentally already implemented something very similar to what you describe except I use a web api interface as the comms layer. One question though; There must be more in play then just being different as you can obviously pinvoke different assemblies. What is different here?

Comment: You can reference .net framework assemblies from .net core applications. Visual studio will warn you though and say that it might not work. I tried making a .net core WPF app and it worked referencing the WPF toolkit library which is strictly .NET framework.
The state of confusion around the different .NET frameworks right now is a complete mess. Hopefully it will be somewhat cleared up with .NET 5

Answer (score 0):

I suggest initially loading up all the DLL libraries.
Then invoke methods after all the DLLs have been loaded.

If you get the error message "Could not load file or assembly ***" find and add that DLL library to the DLL library folder.

The next time you compile and run the app, it will load the missing library and should not complain when you invoke the method.

I have successfully done this. Paste your code for more advice.

Answer (score 0):

The .NET Framework supported this via the Global Assembly Cache (GAC). The .NET Framework knew to look at the GAC and follow any Assembly redirects and load up the latest installed compatible version of the assembly needed.

As far as I know, this isn't the case with .NET Core. The closest you can get to it is using [Framework Dependent Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/index).

I am not sure what happens when you try to load a .NET Framework assembly in a .NET Core environment, but I do not think it is supported. For example, I believe that System.Windows.Forms isn't part of .NET Core or .NET Standard 2.0. So I guess my answer you your question is no. [This post by Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceANETCoreLibraryInWinFormsOrNETStandardExplained.aspx) might help you understand the issue better. .NET Standard exists to allow you to build libraries that can run on .NET Core OR .NET Framework OR Xamarin, each of those being a separate runtime.

Libraries that need to work on both .net core & .net framework have to explicitly be compiled to do so (via .NET Standard which targets the common subset). The runtimes are basically different, and incompatible. Here is another link that lists some of the incompatibilities you have to overcome : [learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/libraries](http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/libraries) ...Only .NET standard libraries can be loaded in both runtimes. You will be able to dynamically load .net core & .net standard libraries, but not .NET framework libraries since the code could use functionality not supported by .NET core.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct about `System.Windows.Forms`. Unfortunately the article by Scott refers to the opposite situation. Referencing Net Core from in a WinForms like environment.

Comment: I was trying to show that since they are different runtimes (with different capabilities) they cannot simply load each others libraries. I edited the answer to elaborate a little more and added an additional link that provides a porting guide that lists some of the incompatibilities. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can load assemblies from disk, however, you will face a few issues.

1. Just because it is compatible doesn't make it the right assembly, you need the right version as well
2. You open a major security issue as someone could inject a DLL that is not "yours"
3. You may need to load dependent assemblies in the right order.

Lucky for you there is already a solution for you that you can implement have a look at the various dependency injection frameworks, in Core, when you deploy your application and have a look at the [Application-Name].deps.json, this is a text file that informs the runtime what to load.

Updating a text file is easy, the rest is framework magic ;-)